# JavaScript submit event on all forms?

Tags: javascript

Im trying to capture the submit event on all forms on a given page (this is dynamic)

What i got so far:

```
/**
* Capture form submits
*/
function addEvent(evnt, elem, func) {
    if (elem.addEventListener) {  // W3C DOM
        elem.addEventListener(evnt,func,false);
    } else if (elem.attachEvent) { // IE DOM
        elem.attachEvent("on"+evnt, func);
    } else { // No much to do
        elem[evnt] = func;
    }
}

var formsCollection = document.forms;
for(var i=0;i<formsCollection.length;i++) {
    //alert(formsCollection[i]);
    var form = document.forms[i];
    addEvent('submit', form, function(e) {
        var validated = true;
        // do form validation
        alert(i);
        if (!validated) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        return validated;
    });        
}
```

Problem is that this only captures the last form.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by only capturing the last form? If you're wondering why the alert box always pops up the same number (specifically, the number of forms on the page) then you need to do some basic research on closures.

Comment: Hint: each one of those event handler functions you create in the loop refer to the exact same variable "i".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues there.

The main one is that all copies of your event handler close over the same `i` variable. They get access to the *variable*, not a copy of the variable as of when they were created. So they're all seeing `i` as it is after the end of the loop. (More: [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html))

The usual fix there is to have a handler builder function:

```
for(var i=0;i<formsCollection.length;i++) {
    //alert(formsCollection[i]);
    var form = document.forms[i];
    addEvent('submit', form, makeHandler(form));
}

function makeHandler(form) {
    return function(e) {
        var validated = true;
        // do form validation using `form`
        if (!validated) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    };
}
```

The second problem is that your `addEvent` doesn't properly handle older versions of IE. Specifically, your handler relies on being able to call `e.preventDefault()` (if that function isn't present, it throws an exception), but that doesn't exist on the event object that you get when you use `attachEvent`. You're also not ensuring that the handler even *has* an event object, because IE using `attachEvent` doesn't pass the event object as an argument; it's a global variable.

To fix that, you can handle the event object and supply a `preventDefault`:

```
function addEvent(evnt, elem, func) {
    if (elem.addEventListener) {  // W3C DOM
        elem.addEventListener(evnt,func,false);
    } else if (elem.attachEvent) { // IE DOM
        elem.attachEvent("on"+evnt, function(e) {
            e = e || window.event; // It won't be there, but just in case
            if (!e.preventDefault) {
                e.preventDefault = preventDefaultOnIE;
            }
            func.call(this, e);
        });
    } else { // No much to do    // <== I recommend throwing an exception here
        elem[evnt] = func;       //     or something, since your script won't work correctly
    }
}

function preventDefaultOnIE() {
    this.returnValue = false;
}
```

If you want to be more thorough and also have `stopPropagation`, do much the same as for `preventDefault` above and use:

```
function stopPropagationOnIE() {
    this.cancelBubble = true;
}
```

Comment: How can i get the data that was submitted on that form?

Comment: @Alosyius: Within the handler, `this` will be the form. (I had a bug in the answer which I've just fixed, you might want to refresh.)

Comment: Thanks! Saved me a bunch of time :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider something a bit simpler. Submit events (and indeed most events) bubble, which means you can handle them further up the DOM tree and therefore use fewer event handlers.

For example:

```
addEvent('submit',document.body,function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var form = e.srcElement || e.target; // cross-browser solution
    var validated = true;
    // do form validation
    alert("I am form number "+(function() {
        // the following is extreme hax, do NOT use this outside of testing!
        var forms = document.getElementsByTagName('form'), l = forms.length, i;
        for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
            if( form == forms[i]) return (i+1)+" of "+l;
        }
    })());
    if( !validated && e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
    return validated;
});
```

Comment: `submit` doesn't bubble in IE (or at least, not any IE old enough to still use `attachEvent`).